# Notebook vs. Kernel: Kernel giving inaccurate results

Tags: kernel, scripting

I am running a code on Mathematica (on Mac OS X) that takes high values for some of the variables. In Notebook, I set the global precision using the following code (which is well documented!) at the top of my 'test_script.m' script to get desired precise results:

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
 s_String /; 
   StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
    Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> s <> "`50." &);
```

It works fine as long as I am using Notebook. However, when I try to run it using MathematicaScript Kernel using the following command line argument:

```
./MathematicaScript -script ~/test_script.m
```

; I am unable to set the precision and the computation gives inaccurate results. Just to make sure, I gave smaller test values to variables and both processes yielded exactly the similar results. This has led me to believe that in MathematicaScript Kernel, the $PreRead command is not effective.

So, Q: How can I set the precision to my desired value in this case; i.e. achieve the same result in terminal as I do in Notebook? Also, why is there a difference when using a Kernel compared to the Notebook.

Answer (score 5):

Per documentation, use `$Pre` for things that are not entering the world as strings. As is the case for the standalone terminal interface.

```
$Pre = (# /. 
     n_?NumberQ /; Precision[n] === MachinePrecision :> 
      SetPrecision[Rationalize[Rationalize[n], 0], 50] &);
```

--- edit ---

After consulting in-office we have something that seems to work better.

```
Clear[preFunc]
SetAttributes[preFunc, HoldAll]; 
preFunc[n_] := 
 ReleaseHold[
  ReplaceAll[Hold[n], 
   aa_Real /; Precision[aa] === MachinePrecision :> 
    SetPrecision[Rationalize[Rationalize[aa], 0], 50]]]
$Pre = preFunc;
```

Here is a test.

```
ee = 3/1.5 + Pi/7
Precision[ee]

(* Out[12]= 2.4487989505128276054946633404685004120281670570536

Out[13]= 50.0879231348 *)
```

Not perfect, but clearly better.

Possibly this could be done using `$PreRead` and substring replacement, I'm not sure.

I will say that I think this is an iffy way to go about handling the underlying problem, which is to use high precision on inputs that might be low precision. I would advocate doing that on a per-computation basis when and as needed, using `SetPrecision` selectively. I have done this sort of thing in the innards of some functions, most notably `NSolve`.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Not the case sadly, both these option have the same effect. That is...none at all.

Comment: (1) Both of what options? (2) If you given an example, the chances of getting an answer that works for you improves considerably.

Comment: Apologies Daniel. Running the script `math -batchinput < testScript.m -batchoutput > res.txt` with `testScript.m` being `$Pre = (# /. n_?NumberQ /; Precision[n] === MachinePrecision :> SetPrecision[Rationalize[Rationalize[n], 0], 50] &); 3/1.5+Pi/7 Precision[%]` results in `res.txt` `2.4487989505128276 MachinePrecision` rather than `2.4487989505128276054946633404685004120281670570536 50.0879` when run through .nb in the GUI.

Comment: Weird. I'll have a look.

Comment: Okay, I looked, and I may need to retract my response. Clearly this is more difficult than I had realized. The problem is that even with setting `HoldXXX` attributes, the `Set` is getting evaluated before the resetting of precision. So this needs more thought and maybe stronger voodoo than I have managed to conjure. Sorry about that.